# ContactManager sort by other Language

Tags: contacts, languages, lenovo

It's a Lenovo a7000-a and it uses ContactManager as a phone app. I have the Language of the device set as english but my contacts are in Greek. The ContactManager does not display Greek letters on te side for quick navigation, only english. Changing the device language to greek fixes the problem but the translations feel awkward. Is there another way?

Comment: try to change the timezone settings or language input for keyboard .